# Fractal dimension of Gaussian white noise is infinite?

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, fractals

I read in [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00354987#page-1) that the fractal dimension of Gaussian white noise is infinite. The paper does not prove it nor give a reference to support it. I failed to find a reference from online searching.

Could someone please explain to me why fractal dimension of Gaussian white noise is infinite? Is Hausdorff dimension infinite too?

I am not sure which definition of Gaussian white noise is appropriate here. I would like to see if this holds for the  [usual definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise) of a Gaussian process with constant power spectral density.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The integral of Guassian white noise would be a Brownian motion process. So, infinite almost everywhere, and uncorrelated point to point. I guess this means that you cannot define an ordinary dimension.

Comment: @BillKleinhans Could you please elaborate, I don't get how Gaussian white noise integrates to BM. Thank you.

Comment: As always, this question is in need of a serious mathematical definition of "white noise" before being tackled.

Comment: @Did Could you please provide a definition. The way I know it (from engineering) Gaussian white noise is a random process $N(t)$ with power spectral density 1 (or constant) and for all $t_i \in [0, T]$ $N(t_i)$ has Gaussian distribution.

Comment: I have none, and [for good reasons](http://mathoverflow.net/q/76274/4661)...

Comment: @Did So what then happens to the original question? Is is meaning less to talk about fractal dimension of Gaussian white noise? Please explain, thanks.

Comment: You want me to explain why, without a proper definition of GWN, a question about the fractal dimension of GWN cannot be answered? Please explain, thanks.